# How to return false with continue in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm developing a code to return True when  a word in a string containing any letter of the alphabet at least once.

I have tried this code.It returns True when a word in a string contains an alphabet.But i need to return False when it didn't find correct matches.

```
def ispangram(word):
    wordlist=word.split(" ")
    alphapet=['a','e','i','o','u']
    for y in (wordlist):
        for x in alphapet:
            if x in y:
                return True
                break
            else:
                continue

worda="gf kj xx"
print(ispangram(worda))
```

Comment: That would be true if any of the letters are in string without any splits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to add a return False statement at the end of the outer loop

```
def ispangram(word):
    wordlist=word.split(" ")
    alphapet=['a','e','i','o','u']
    for y in (wordlist):
        for x in alphapet:
            if x in y:
                return True
                break
            else:
                continue
    return False

worda="gf kj xx"
print(ispangram(worda))
```

Answer (score 0):

-1 Remove break after return

-2 return False instead of continue

Answer (score 0):

You can return false after the loop which only gets called if you never return true. You don't need the break, continue or even the else: statement, as the continue happens anyway and the break will never be called since the return happens first.

```
def ispangram(word):
    wordlist=word.split(" ")
    alphapet=['a','e','i','o','u']
    for y in (wordlist):
        for x in alphapet:
            if x in y:
                return True

    return False
```